# How does Badiou summarise Levinas' approach to ethics?

Tags: ethics, badiou, levinas

In Badiou’s opening paragraphs he offers an account of Lévinas’s concern with philosophy and its hostility to an ethical relation to the Other. In Badiou’s characterisation of Lévinas, why is it impossible to ‘arrive at authentic thought of the Other’ through inherited philosophy; what alternative tradition does Lévinas turn to and what does this offer him, according to Badiou?